# How to take input from a external API and email it

Tags: javascript, html, email

In class, we got challenged with making websites that would be deemed "malicious" or untrustful. We are on a security section in the unit

I'm making a website that when a person goes onto it an external API (http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp) catches basic information like state, city, zip code etc. I want to send the data received when a person enters the website to an email address. However, I have 0 idea how to do this.

I've looked up youtube videos but found nothing that leads me anywhere close to this topic

here are some placeholders from the API. I want to take the result from geoplugin_city() for example and send it in an email.

````js
<script language="Javascript"> 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = geoplugin_city();
    console.log("Welcome to our visitors from "+geoplugin_city()+", "+geoplugin_countryName());
    console.log("Testing"+geoplugin_region());```
````

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want is to pass the data to your server and then use an email client library, e.g. [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) or [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/email-api/), to send to where you want.

You don't really want to do this on your client, as in order to send any email, you'd need to authenticate... unless there is an API that will email a message to an email without a specific user account.  But you will need an API key that you wont want to hardcode into your client code.

So:

1. Collect your data via client javascript script.
2. Send your data to your server.
3. Use a client library (authenticated, at the least using an API key, but depends on your choice of email provider) on your server to
   send your data to your designated email.

Something to consider would be to batch your data dumps.  You could log to a file and periodically read that file and dump it to the email, versus sending every time a user hits your site.  That could eat your API quota really fast (there usually is a quota, especially for free accounts).  The period would be something you'd need to evaluate yourself.

You could also set up multiple emails with that provider in the event that your initial cap gets hit or gets shut down. It seems obvious, but you'd want to use disposable emails here.